# Attempting to setup static IP block with ATT Uverse and IP Passthrough to ASUS router

Tags: dns, router, nat, subnet

I am trying to accomplish the following setup:

NVG599 <> ASUS RT-AC88U <> Static device

I have an Ubuntu Server running Apache which has been configured to use an internal address 192.x.x.x as well as one of the static IP addresses. I know Apache is running / listening / working. If I browse to the internal address I get the default Apache page. Ubuntu firewall is disabled. I actually have a domain setup that points to this IP address 'http://thelavender.net'

Normally the ATT RG would handle the second subnet / static IP block. What I cannot figure out is how the ASUS would handle these now that its basically taking over all routing duties.

There is a cascading router option in the ATT RG and I have seen some people talking about using this instead. Is this correct?

**EDIT**

Thinking back, I think 1:1 NAT is what I really need here correct?

**EDIT 2**
I tried using something along the lines of this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# to restore this configuration, it needs to be saved to /jffs/scripts/nat-start
# on the router.
#
ifconfig eth0:0 WanIP1 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d WanIP1 -j DNAT --to-destination     192.168.1.10
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.10 -j SNAT --to WanIP1
#
ifconfig eth0:1 WanIP2 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d WanIP2 -j DNAT --to-destination     192.168.1.11
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.11 -j SNAT --to WanIP2
#
ifconfig eth0:2 WanIP3 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d WanIP3 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.12 -j SNAT --to WanIP3
#
# Port forwards, in case the webui doesn't work, but i think it will.  uncomment below if needed.
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.1.10 -j ACCEPT
```

I only tried the first group and put this in the nat-start script for Merlin to pick up. When I did this and restarted the router, it refused to pick up the WAN IP from the RG.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Voted down but no explanation as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVG599 LAN address: 192.168.0.254 / 255.255.255.0

RT-AC88U WAN address: 192.168.0.1 / 255.255.255.0
RT-AC88U LAN address: 192.168.1.1 / 255.255.255.0

NVG599 Cascaded Router: Enabled
Cascaded Router Address: 192.168.0.1
Network Address: 107.218.164.224
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248

Server: 192.168.1.10 and 107.218.164.225

Startup script for the router:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# tell it where to find the server

ip ro add 107.218.164.225/32 via 192.168.1.10
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -s 107.218.164.225/32 -j RETURN

#
# servers 2-N go here
......
#
# catch-all for everything else on the LAN
#
# this will double-NAT everything and will end up using the NVG's dynamic IP which is outside of the static IP block
##iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.1
#
# this uses one of the public IPs
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 107.218.164.230
```

And script for the server if need be

```
#!/bin/sh
#
ifconfig eth0:1 107.218.164.225/29
ip ro repl default via 192.168.1.1 src 107.218.164.225
```